# Run Axios on AngularJs button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, axios

I'm working with AngularJs and Bootstrap. What i need is to make post on an API that have an app key and app token. First i've tried with ajax, but i get an 405 response:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://thelink'
>   from origin 'http://mylink' has been blocked by
>   CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

This is my code:

```
       $scope.sendThis = function(){
        var destinyData = {
            "FieldId": 1,
            "Name": "Test",
            "Text": "Test",
            "IsActive": true,
            "Position": 105
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: 'thelink',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'API-AppKey': 'thekey',
                'AppToken': 'thetoken'
            },
            data: destinyData,
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("Something's wrong!");
            }
        });
    }
```

And my HTML view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendThis()">Send</button>
```

Then i read that i can use Axios to make the request on my backend. So, i installed the axios library (`npm axios`) and tested:

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'thelink',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'API-AppKey': 'thekey', 'AppToken': 'thetoken'},
    data: {
        "FieldId": 113,
        "Name": "Test",
        "Text": "Test",
        "IsActive": true,
        "Position": 545
    }
})
.then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
})
```

And it works! Now my question: how can i trigger the method post of Axios on a button click, just like my first test (`$scope.sendThis`)?

And a second question: there's a way to generate an api with express to call the axios example on NodeJs?

Hope you can help me. Thanx in advance.

I'm using Javascript, AngularJs, Bootstrap and NodeJs

Comment: Your problem is CORS or using axios on angularjs ?

Comment: Yes, that's my problem. But i've found a solution. As i need to save the same data in another api, i just add the Axios code into my method post. I've tested and works fine. The same data was sended to both apis. Thanx